# How many bytes does BufferedReader really read using .read() method?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In a simple sever-client application I'm reading data this way:

```
 if((value=in.read())!=-1) {
   if(protocol.newChar((char)value, input)) {
      //Consider curent buffer data a message
      protocol.receiveMessage(input.toString());
      //Clear some buffer
      input.setLength(0);
   }
 }
```

Now in java documentations they say that the method `read` reads a single character "*as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached*".

Reading characters as integers stuff aside, I'm still confused by the results this function gives me - I'm sending integer as 4 bytes (I put it in byte array and send it).

On the receiving side, I see this in the console:

```
Received character:   [0]
Received character:   [0]
Received character:   [0]
Received character: [8]
```

Produced by this code, where `current` is a `char` returned by `in.read()`:

```
Log.debug("Received character: "+current+" ["+(int)current+"]");
```

Obviously I'm confused what happened. Did sending function convert bytes back into chars?

<sub>During debugging, I have discovered a funny thing - the `\0` in netbeans console can be copyed along with other text. During pasting, only data before first `\0` will be pasted. (windows 7)</sub>

Comment: What integer did your write?  8?

Comment: Yes. And integer has 4 bytes. Char in java has 2 bytes. So how can integer produce 4 chars?

Comment: Where/how do you get `current`?

Comment: Current is actually 1st argument of `protocol.newChar((char)value, input)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Reader` reads `char`s, not `byte`s. It often does so (eventually, depending on the reader, its delegate, etc) by reading bytes and converting them to `char`s, either by a charset you manually specify, or by the system default. [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) is generally where this happens. From that class' javadocs:

> Each invocation of one of an InputStreamReader's read() methods may cause one or more bytes to be read from the underlying byte-input stream. To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.

So the answer is really, "it's implementation defined," but it'll be at *least* as many bytes are required to form one char. Without knowing your charset, we can't say what that is; it's 1 for the "usual" chars in UTF-8, 2 for all chars in UTF-16, etc. But `InputStreamReader` allows itself wiggle room to read ahead for efficiency, by some indeterminate amount.

If you're using UTF-8 (a common default) and sending the four bytes `[0, 0, 0, 8]`, then these correspond to four chars: `[\u0000, \u0000, \u0000, \u0008]`. In that case, it would make sense that sending an integer as 4 bytes would cause you to receive 4 chars.

Comment: I was not asking how many bytes the buffered reader reads internally and stores in its buffer! I'm asking how many bytes are interpreted as one return value.

Comment: Well, it's still no use. It sometimes (as in case of the int) reads per-byte and sometimes (in case of string) reads 2 bytes. I just wonder why things can't be clear in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by in the case of int or string. Do you mean `read()` vs `readLine()`? What is it you're really trying to read? If you're trying to read strings, use a `Reader/BufferedReader` as you're doing. But if you're trying to read anything else, you should use an `InputStream/BufferedInputStream`. Java draws a clear distinction between `char`s (unicode characters) and `byte`s ("raw" data). The only reason that `read()` returns an `int` rather than `char` is that it wants to return `-1` to signify the end of the stream, and `char`s in Java are unsigned (so can't be `-1`).

Comment: ... and specifically, if you're trying to put in an integer via its 4-byte, two's complement representation -- then you need to read out 4 _bytes_ and put them back into an `int` via bitwise operations (or use something like Guava's [`Ints.fromByteArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#fromByteArray(byte[]))). That means using an `InputStream`, not `Reader`. You'd only use the reader if you sent over a _string_ `"0008"` (unicode values `\u0030 \u0030 \u0030 \u0038` -- so in UTF-8, ints `48 48 48 56`).

Comment: I will keep debuging and will post another question as soon as I get to the core of the problem. This one was too broad. By the way, I wonder why did Java deeloppers decide to create *signed* byte and *unsigned* char.
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No, there is _only_ an unsigned char (type `char`). An `int` is just an integer, not a signed `char`. This `read()` method is simply using an int as a hack to return "`char` or -1.". Typically you would use it by doing something like `if (readValue < 0) { streamIsDone(); } else { char c = (char) readValue; handleChar(c); }` Btw, if you don't quite get the distinction between bytes and unicode code points (ie, `char`s), I would highly recommend http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: Re-reading your previous comment, you're of course right: signed char, unsigned byte. I thought you had written "unsigned char." Chars pretty much have to be unsigned, because unicode code points are unsigned. I would speculate that bytes are signed to be consistent with the other integer types (`long`, `int` and `short`).

Answer (score 0):

> Did sending function convert bytes back into chars?

`read` states [`Reads a single character.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29).

**Send**: You're writing a **4-byte** integer, apparently consisting of the bytes 0, 0, 0, 8.
**Read**: You only read **two** bytes, **one** character, each time.

```
private char cb[];
...
return cb[nextChar++];
```

So, either you write only two bytes, or you read 4 bytes and interpret them as a 4-bit integer.

**We need more of your code to answer your original question.**

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader.read() consumes one character's worth of bytes per call.  The number of bytes per character depends on the character encoding.  On most platforms, the default character encoding is something like UTF-8, which usually uses only a single byte per character.

Note that the platform character encoding may be different from Java's internal representation of characters, which uses two bytes per character.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of BufferedReader.read() is the same as described in Reader.read().
The only difference is that it only reads data from the underlying stream if the buffer is empty.

The bytes are converted to characters but this depends on the charset. If the charset is UTF-8 and one byte is higher than 127 you would receive less than 4 characters.